# What is a UDID? Can I test a game on other iOS devices after I added only 1 device?

Tags: ios, udid

I am creating `Apple Developer Account` and they asked me to provide a **[UDID](http://unity3diy.blogspot.com/2014/02/what-is-udid-ios-dev-asked-you-for-your.html)** I have 1 `iOS` device. If I give them my `ID` and after it I change my `iPhone` what should I do next?

Can i test app on the next device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Unique Device Identifier** - The series of numbers and letters used by Apple and developers to uniquely identify your iPhone, iPod touch, and iPad.

You are allowed to register up to **100** `iOS` devices for testing and `Ad Hoc` distribution per membership year. Although you may remove a device from your account, it will continue to count against your `100` device limit.

At the start of your new membership year, Team Agents or Admins can sign in to the `iOS Provisioning Portal` to remove listed devices and restore the available device count to `100` devices. Be sure to remove all devices you no longer use for development prior to adding any new devices.

You can add a new device in the Devices section in the Developer Portal. If you add a UDID of your current iPhone and then get a new one, you will have to add the UDID of the new iPhone as well. Basically, you can only test on the devices which you added to the portal.

[image]

[image]

Source: [iOS Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/account-management.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can test on up to 100 devices, you add those devices at your developer portal at https://developer.apple.com/

Click member center, login, and select Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles.

UDID is there to make sure that you can only install/give your app to limited number of devices outside of AppStore.

This site explains nicely how to find your UDID: http://whatsmyudid.com/